# preg_replace on the matches of another preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a feeling that I might be missing something very basic. Anyways heres the scenario:

I'm using preg_replace to convert `===inputA===inputB===` to `<a href="inputB">inputA</a>`
This is what I'm using

```
$new = preg_replace('/===(.*?)===(.*?)===/', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $old);
```

Its working fine alright, but I also need to further restrict inputB so its like this

```
preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '', every Link or inputB);
```

So basically, in the first code, where you see `$2` over there I need to perform operations on that `$2` so that it only contains `\w` as you can see in the second code. So the final result should be like this:
Convert `===The link===link's page===` to `<a href="linkspage">The link</a>`

I have no idea how to do this, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there already is an accepted answer: this is what the `/e` modifier or `preg_replace_callback()` are for:

```
echo preg_replace(
    '/===(.*?)===(.*?)===/e',
    '"<a href=\"".preg_replace("/[^\w]/","","$2")."\">$1</a>"',
    '===inputA===in^^putB===');

//Output: <a href="inputB">inputA</a>
```

Or:

```
function _my_url_func($vars){
   return '<a href="'.strtoupper($vars[1]).'">'.$vars[2].'</a>';
}

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/===(.*?)===(.*?)===/',
    '_my_url_func',
    '===inputA===inputB===');

//Output: <a href="INPUTA">inputB</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) on the first one to get the 2 matches into variables, and then use preg_replace() on the one you want further checks on?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do extract the matches from the first regex (`preg_match`) and treat thoses results and then put them back in a HTML form ?

Comment: I was thinking about this as well, however it would be a good idea to show some code on how to do this.

Comment: Did a preg_match_all, then used str_replace in a loop and finally a preg_replace. But I posted the question because i was wondering if there was a way to perform operations directly on the "$2". Thanks anyway :)